# Formik dispatch Redux action after valid field change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, formik

I've built this sandbox React application that uses Formik forms.

I want to dispatch a Redux action if the email field validation fires and is valid.
I want to dispatch the action to do some lookup from the users email. This action will update redux state and populate some other field on my form.

So this dispatch would happen if the email field was valid. The other fields could be invalid and I haven't submitted the form yet.

How do I do that? I can't find any documentation on this!

https://codesandbox.io/s/x32yoo242q

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand the question... You'd set up redux and then call an action creator from the handleSubmit instead of just alerting... Seems your sandbox doesn't have redux set up at all...

Comment: Sorry - i mean id like to fire the action when the individual field has changed and is valid. Rather when the entire form is completed and valid.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand... in the sandbox name is missing from the input which is how Formik identifies the fields and much more.... You’d get a lot more value out of this 40 min vid than a paragraph here... here you go: https://youtu.be/yNiJkjEwmpw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a reusable custom `component` that calls a secondary action on `input` updates. In this case, it'll dispatch an `action` (redux action) if the input is valid and has a value, and/or optionally dispatch a secondary action if invalid.

**Update**: Utilize `componentDidUpdate`. It's less verbose and requires less manual field level handling. In addition, you should also `debounce` the function to avoid a lot of redux action triggers.

**Working example (email)**:

[image: Edit Formik Redux Yup Example]

**Working example (Material UI Select)**:

[image: Edit Formik Redux Yup MaterialUI]

---

**components/Input** (custom component -- `componentDidUpdate` controls whether or not to call `validateField`)

```
import React, { Fragment, PureComponent } from "react";

class Input extends PureComponent {
  componentDidUpdate = prevProps => {
    const { errors, value } = this.props;
    if (errors !== prevProps.errors || value !== prevProps.value) {
      this.props.validateField({ errors, value });
    }
  };

  render = () => {
    const { errors, label, name, touched, validateField, ...rest } = this.props;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <label htmlFor={name} style={{ display: "block" }}>
          {label}
        </label>
        <input {...rest} name={name} />
        {errors && touched && (
          <div style={{ color: "red", marginTop: ".5rem" }}>{errors}</div>
        )}
      </Fragment>
    );
  };
}

export default Input;
```

**containers/Form** (`validateField` controls the redux action)

```
import debounce from "lodash/debounce";
import React from "react";
import { withFormik } from "formik";
import Input from "../../components/Input";
import DisplayFormikState from "../../components/DisplayFormState";
import { resetMessage, setMessage } from "../../actions/message";
import store from "../../store";
import * as Yup from "yup";

const formikEnhancer = withFormik({
  validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string()
      .email("Invalid email address")
      .required("Email is required!")
  }),
  mapPropsToValues: props => ({
    email: ""
  }),
  handleSubmit: (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    const payload = {
      ...values
    };

    setTimeout(() => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(payload, null, 2));
      setSubmitting(false);
    }, 1000);
  },
  displayName: "MyForm"
});

const handleFormReset = handleReset => {
  store.dispatch(resetMessage());
  handleReset();
};

const validateField = debounce(
  ({ errors, value }) =>
    !errors && value
      ? store.dispatch(setMessage())
      : store.dispatch(resetMessage()),
  500
);

const MyForm = props => {
  const {
    values,
    touched,
    dirty,
    errors,
    handleBlur,
    handleChange,
    handleReset,
    handleSubmit,
    isSubmitting
  } = props;

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Input
        name="email"
        label="Email"
        type="email"
        placeholder="Enter an email address."
        errors={errors.email}
        value={values.email}
        touched={touched.email}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
        validateField={validateField}
      />
      <button
        type="button"
        className="outline"
        onClick={() => handleFormReset(handleReset)}
        disabled={!dirty || isSubmitting}
      >
        Reset
      </button>
      <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
        Submit
      </button>

      <DisplayFormikState {...props} />
    </form>
  );
};

export default formikEnhancer(MyForm);
```

Comment: Super detailed kick ass answer. Thanks for throwing in the redux stuff too. /pewpew

Comment: Any idea on how to do the same sort of eventing with a Material ui select box? I can't seem to transpose the logic to a select box. So instead of an email dispatching a redux action, a selection in the drop down would. There doesnt seem to be an onBlur event to hook into

Comment: Create a codesandbox example of what you want and I'll take a look at it (you can fork mine so you don't have to start from scratch).

Comment: Many thanks sir! Will send crypto lol.
I've added a drop down box via material-ui. It doesnt have an on blur option. I want it to dispatch a redux action, when the selection is valid (not null).

https://codesandbox.io/s/v01jw1z5k3

Many thanks!

Comment: OK think I figured it. I needed to add componentDidUpdate to my DropDown component and to check that there was a value and no errors before invoking handleblur.

Comment: Come to think of it `componentDidUpdate` is a better approach overall. Updated answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I wonder why it gets double called and needs a debounce

Comment: Anytime the value is updated `componentDidUpdate` is called. So if a user is typing, debounce will prevent those calls during activity (it'll wait 500ms until after they have stopped to call the `validateField` function one time).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest and most straightforward way to achieve what you want is by using the **`onBlur`** handler of your email input. You can extend the default handler by doing the following:

```
<input
  id="email"
  placeholder="Enter your email"
  type="email"
  value={values.email}
  onChange={handleChange}
  onBlur={e => {
    handleBlur(e);
    if (!errors.email) {
      console.log("dispatch: ", e.currentTarget.value);
    }
  }}
/>
```

By also calling the Formik's **`handleBlur`** first you keep the default validation behavior, while also adding your own afterwards. Your form is validating **`onChange`** as well as **`onBlur`** so **`errors.email`** should always give an accurate representation of validity for the email input, which we can use to dispatch if the email is valid on blur (In my example I'm just logging something to the console to illustrate). Check out the **sandbox** to see it in action:

[image: Edit Formik 1.2 x React Select Example]